# How to install apache airflow on windows without docker without enabling windows linux subsystem on pycharm

Tags: windows, pycharm, airflow

I want to make pipeline. I want to install apache airflow on windows without docker without enabling windows linux subsystem on pycharm.
I tried following commands:-
pip install apache-airflow
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install apache-airflow [celery]

I created directory and also created airflow.cfg .
In airflow.cfg file , i have added following configuration

(AIRFLOW_HOME = /path/to/airflow/installation
AIRFLOW_CONN_DATABASE_URL = postgresql://user: password@localhost:5432/database)

Then created dags/helloworld.py
In this .py file i have added some code snippet.
But when i run the following  command:-
Airflow scheduler
Its giving error:-
Saying
Module not found:- no module named pwd

Is  there any way to install apache airflow on windows without docker without enabling windows linux subsystem

I tried all the things discussed above. I just expect to run airflow on pycharm on windows